# Accidentally deleted an iOS framework, is there anyway to download it

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

in iOS5.0, i accidentally deleted the messageUI.framework, now it does not exist in the Xcode library. Is there any way I can download just the framework or will I have to reinstall Xcode to get the framework back?

Thanks in advance for your help?

Comment: reinstall Xcode to get the framework as its best u might not know how many framework u have deleted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your Project's Build Phases go to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section and press the + button.

In the search field type "message" and it should come back up.  Select it and it'll be added.

Comment: tried that, but it did not work. still showing up as red. I also tried quitting out of Xcode totally and then restarting the project. still nothing.

Comment: Hmmm... In that case I endorse @Prince's advice of re-installing Xcode.  Not a small download unfortunately.

Comment: did that and it worked! :-( i thought there should be another way

Answer (score 1):

Above method will not work if your xCode's location is different. For that Open xCode click top project blue icon. Click Target-> build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Now right or control click any existing framework and Show in Finder.

This way you will get all existing framework's default location. Now go to that location and add your deleted framework again.

Restart xcode then you will see your deleted framework as it was before.